How to sort an API response using a dropdown?
`Building a movie search site for a project using OMDb API. Everything populates as expected but i can't seem to figure out how to Sort them by name from my drop down. Any help would be appreciated.  I've tried a few different variations of sorting to get it to work and none have. I'm sure its just something stupid i'm doing but would love a bit of guidance. Thanks
HTML
 <select name="" id="filter">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Sort</option>
      <option value="Alphabetical" 
          onclick="orderListBy(post.Title).toSorted">A-Z</option>
</select>

<div class="post-list">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="post__title">
          
        </div>
        <p class="post__body">
          
        </p>
        <figure class="post__img">
          
        </figure>
     </div>
</div>

Javascript
const postListEl = document.querySelector('.post-list')
const Title = localStorage.getItem("Title")


async function onSearchChange(event) {
    const Title = event.target.value
    setTimeout(() =>{
   renderPosts(Title)}, 1000)
}

async function renderPosts(Title) {
    const posts = await fetch(
      `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=67b7f307&s=${Title}`
    );
    const postsData = await posts.json();
    postListEl.innerHTML = postsData.Search.map((post) => postHTML(post)).join(
      ""
    );
  }
  
  function postHTML(post) {
    return `
          <div class="post">
          <div class="post__title">
            ${post.Title}
          </div>
          <p class="post__body">
            ${post.Year}
          </p>
          <figure class="post__img"><img src="${post.Poster}"</figure>
        </div>
    `;
  }

function orderListBy(event) {
  return function (a, b) {
      if (a[post.Title] > b[post.Title]) {
          return 1;
      }
      else if (a[post.Title] < b[post.Title]) {
          return -1;
      }
      return 0;
  }
}


Can you fix the format of the code - the HTML is all over the place

Not sure how you mean. If you'd like i can just link the github for it. May be easier than trying to pull small bits of the HTML.

IT Goldman yeah i was just kind of trying anything i could think of

Look at it ... what is the SORT A-Z at the top? why don't you have a closing </select> tag - why is it indented so much? why so many blank lines? Seriously it's hard to read, and so easily fixed

Your <select> element isn't closed.

New to coding. New to this site. When copy/pasting to this site that's how it showed up. IDK where the Sort A-Z came from honestly.

select element is now closed still no change. Still doesn't work

The onclick event on the  tag doesn't work because  doesn't handle events like onclick in a select dropdown. You should use an event listener on the  element instead.

The orderListBy function is intended to sort posts, but it is currently returning a comparator function instead of directly performing the sort.

How would i modify that to sort by the title once the response is returned?

okay so put the onclick on the select gotcha.

Ok let's build an example. this is for the select part:


function sortBy(prop) {
  if (!prop) {
    return;
  }
  alert(prop)

}
<select onchange="sortBy(this.value)">
  <option>Sort By</option>
  <option value="name">Name</option>
  <option value="year">Year</option>
</select>



For the sorting you can use function from this answer.
Let's combine:


function sortBy(prop) {
  if (!prop) {
    return;
  }
  renderList(list.sort(getSortMethod(prop)))
}


function renderList(list) {
  console.log(list)

}

let list = [{
    name: 'Mark',
    year: 2021,
  },
  {
    name: 'Anne',
    year: 2020,
  },
  {
    name: 'James',
    year: 1988,
  },
]


function getSortMethod() {
  var _args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return function(a, b) {
    for (var x in _args) {
      var ax = a[_args[x].substring(1)];
      var bx = b[_args[x].substring(1)];
      var cx;

      ax = typeof ax == "string" ? ax.toLowerCase() : ax / 1;
      bx = typeof bx == "string" ? bx.toLowerCase() : bx / 1;

      if (_args[x].substring(0, 1) == "-") {
        cx = ax;
        ax = bx;
        bx = cx;
      }
      if (ax != bx) {
        return ax < bx ? -1 : 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
<select onchange="sortBy(this.value)">
  <option>Sort By</option>
  <option value="+name">Name (asc)</option>
  <option value="-name">Name (desc)</option>
  <option value="+year">Year (asc)</option>
  <option value="-year">Year (desc)</option>
</select>



